# Active Record JDBC Derby Adapter interpreting smallint columns as boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, derby, jrubyonrails, activerecord-jdbc

I am using the activerecord-jdbcderby-adapter gem with jruby 1.7.9 and rails 4.0.2 with a legacy Derby database.

My Derby tables have several smallint fields.

These are all being interpreted by the adapter as boolean (i.e. the int value is lost).

Is there a workaround for this (other than changing the column types)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

currently not (no-one needed it so far) but it can be done with a few copy-pastes e.g. it's happening for the Firebird adapter (and a few others as well) :

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/lib/arjdbc/firebird/adapter.rb#L43

so something like that needs to be added somewhere here :

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/lib/arjdbc/derby/adapter.rb#L56

looking for a PR :)